# unable to download the csv file in via rest api

Tags: angular

I'm trying to download the CSV content file using the REST API in Codeigniter 4 but it not working, I'm fetching the data from the database which I need to download via rest API.
In the controller I found this:

```
return $this->response->download('test.csv', $data); // $data is string

Front in angular:
const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('responseType', 'blob');
this.http.get(path, { headers }).subscribe(
  (res) => {},
  (error) => {console.error(error)}
);
```

But not working, am I missing something?

Please guide me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to load an csv file in the app, it needs to be a application/octet-stream. You do this by setting arraybuffer as the response type in the headers.

```js
this.httpClient.get(path, {
  headers,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
```

But if you are trying to download a csv to the users computer you should just be able to use `window.open('path to csv')` and the browser will download it for them.